# sklearn pipeline IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python, scikit-learn, traceback

I'm trying to get the Skype-Type project to work with my own training data but I'm stuck with the sklearn pipeline
https://github.com/SPRITZ-Research-Group/Skype-Type

I have two arrays one filled with labels (the pressed keystrokes) and the other one with the sound data like this:

```
['esc' '0' '1' '2' 'e' 'esc' 'oe' 'r' 'v' 'ae' 'w' 'l' 'j' 'd' 'o' 't' 'w'
[0.004483204561239551 0.13001293227594699 0.026899227367437304 ...
```

In the next step I'm trying to build the pipeline according to this code

```
# Load pipeline steps
# 1 - Feature extraction
pipeline = []
if not args.no_feature_extraction:
    pipeline.append((args.features, getattr(dst.miners, args.features)()))

if not args.no_scaling:
    pipeline.append(('Scaler', MinMaxScaler()))

# 2 - Feature selector and classifier
classifier = getattr(importlib.import_module(args.classifier[1]), args.classifier[0])()

if not args.no_feature_selection:
    stepcount = int(f_X.shape[0] / 10)
    pipeline.append(('Feature Selection',
                     RFECV(classifier, step=stepcount, cv=args.folds, verbose=0)))

pipeline.append(('Classifier', classifier))

clf = Pipeline(pipeline)   

clf.fit(f_X, f_y)
```

Which will create the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Raik/PycharmProjects/skypetype-test/generate_model.py", line 218, in <module>
    clf.fit(f_X, f_y)
  File "C:\Users\Raik\PycharmProjects\skypetype-test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 265, in fit
    Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Users\Raik\PycharmProjects\skypetype-test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 230, in _fit
    **fit_params_steps[name])
  File "C:\Users\Raik\PycharmProjects\skypetype-test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\memory.py", line 355, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Raik\PycharmProjects\skypetype-test\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 616, in _fit_transform_one
    res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)
  File "C:\Users\Raik\PycharmProjects\skypetype-test\dst\miners.py", line 15, in transform
    appendEnergy=False).flatten() for sample in X])
  File "C:\Users\Raik\PycharmProjects\skypetype-test\venv\lib\site-packages\python_speech_features\base.py", line 28, in mfcc
    feat,energy = fbank(signal,samplerate,winlen,winstep,nfilt,nfft,lowfreq,highfreq,preemph,winfunc)
  File "C:\Users\Raik\PycharmProjects\skypetype-test\venv\lib\site-packages\python_speech_features\base.py", line 54, in fbank
    signal = sigproc.preemphasis(signal,preemph)
  File "C:\Users\Raik\PycharmProjects\skypetype-test\venv\lib\site-packages\python_speech_features\sigproc.py", line 118, in preemphasis
    return numpy.append(signal[0],signal[1:]-coeff*signal[:-1])
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

The pipeline keys from clf.get_params().keys look like the following

```
['Feature Selection__estimator__penalty', 'Scaler__copy', 'Feature Selection__step', 'Feature Selection__scoring', 'Feature Selection__n_jobs', 'Feature Selection__estimator__n_jobs', 'Feature Selection__estimator__multi_class', 'Feature Selection__estimator__tol', 'Classifier__multi_class', 'Feature Selection__estimator__verbose', 'MFCC', 'Scaler__feature_range', 'Classifier__class_weight', 'Feature Selection__estimator__solver', 'Classifier__solver', 'Classifier__dual', 'Feature Selection__cv', 'Feature Selection__estimator__max_iter', 'Feature Selection__estimator', 'Classifier__random_state', 'memory', 'Classifier__fit_intercept', 'Classifier__max_iter', 'Classifier__penalty', 'Classifier__C', 'Feature Selection__estimator__dual', 'Feature Selection__verbose', 'Classifier__intercept_scaling', 'Classifier__tol', 'Classifier__warm_start', 'Feature Selection__estimator__random_state', 'Feature Selection__estimator__warm_start', 'Classifier', 'Feature Selection__estimator__fit_intercept', 'Feature Selection__estimator__C', 'Scaler', 'Feature Selection__estimator__class_weight', 'Classifier__verbose', 'steps', 'Feature Selection', 'Classifier__n_jobs', 'Feature Selection__estimator__intercept_scaling', 'Feature Selection__min_features_to_select']
```

And if I print the Pipeline after building I get this output:

```
print clf

['Feature Selection__estimator__penalty', 'Scaler__copy', 'Feature Selection__step', 'Feature Selection__scoring', 'Feature Selection__n_jobs', 'Feature Selection__estimator__n_jobs', 'Feature Selection__estimator__multi_class', 'Feature Selection__estimator__tol', 'Classifier__multi_class', 'Feature Selection__estimator__verbose', 'MFCC', 'Scaler__feature_range', 'Classifier__class_weight', 'Feature Selection__estimator__solver', 'Classifier__solver', 'Classifier__dual', 'Feature Selection__cv', 'Feature Selection__estimator__max_iter', 'Feature Selection__estimator', 'Classifier__random_state', 'memory', 'Classifier__fit_intercept', 'Classifier__max_iter', 'Classifier__penalty', 'Classifier__C', 'Feature Selection__estimator__dual', 'Feature Selection__verbose', 'Classifier__intercept_scaling', 'Classifier__tol', 'Classifier__warm_start', 'Feature Selection__estimator__random_state', 'Feature Selection__estimator__warm_start', 'Classifier', 'Feature Selection__estimator__fit_intercept', 'Feature Selection__estimator__C', 'Scaler', 'Feature Selection__estimator__class_weight', 'Classifier__verbose', 'steps', 'Feature Selection', 'Classifier__n_jobs', 'Feature Selection__estimator__intercept_scaling', 'Feature Selection__min_features_to_select']
Pipeline(memory=None,
     steps=[('MFCC', MFCC()), ('Scaler', MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(0, 1))), ('Feature Selection', RFECV(cv=5,
   estimator=LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='warn',
          n_jobs=None, pena...penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='warn',
          tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False))])
```

I'm stuck with this error for days now and I have no clue how to fix it. Do you have any suggestions?

**EDIT**: I added the python script `dst.miners` where `python_speech_features` are called below

```
import python_speech_features as sf
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
import numpy as np


class BaseMiner(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y):
        return self


class MFCC(BaseMiner):
    @staticmethod
    def transform(X):
        return np.array([sf.mfcc(sample, 44100, 0.01, 0.0025, 32, 32, preemph=0, highfreq=12000, ceplifter=0,
                       appendEnergy=False).flatten() for sample in X])
```

**EDIT2**: Debugging of the `python_speech_features\sigproc.py", line 118, in preemphasis`

Input value for `signal = 0.004483204561239551` the coefficient is set to zero `coeff = 0`

```
def preemphasis(signal,coeff=0.95):
    """perform preemphasis on the input signal.

    :param signal: The signal to filter.
    :param coeff: The preemphasis coefficient. 0 is no filter, default is 0.95.
    :returns: the filtered signal.
    """
    return numpy.append(signal[0],signal[1:]-coeff*signal[:-1])
```

Comment: Totally unfamiliar with this, but shouldn't the sound data be 2-dimensional?  It's the output from `python_speech_features.base.mfcc` (wrapped in the local package `dst`)?

Comment: According to the python_speech_features parameters it should be a 
"signal – the audio signal from which to compute features. Should be an N*1 array"

Comment: But that function gets run on each sample (`... for sample in X` in `MFCC.transform`). How much of the Skype-Type script are you using? Did you have that process .wav file(s)?